# how to connect signals and slots between two QObjects using movetoThread in two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have two classes:A and B，both of them subclass from the QObject.

```
class A:public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
A();
~A();
}
```

i just referred to [this article](https://john.nachtimwald.com/2015/05/02/effective-threading-using-qt/).
Then in the GUI （say the main Thread）I try to exchange data between A and B in different threads using

```
pA = new A();
QThread *workerThread = new QThread;
pA->moveToThread(workerThread);
connect(workerThread , SIGNAL(started()), pA, SLOT(doWork()));
connect(pA, SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread , SLOT(quit()));
connect(pA, SIGNAL(finished()), pA, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(workerThread , SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread , SLOT(deleteLater()));
workerThread ->start();
pB = new B();
connect(pA,SIGNAL(sigProduce(double)),pB,SLOT(slotConsume(double)));//I just don't know where to put this line
QThread *workerThread = new QThread;
pB ->moveToThread(workerThread);
connect(workerThread , SIGNAL(started()), pB , SLOT(doWork()));
connect(pB , SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread , SLOT(quit()));
connect(pB , SIGNAL(finished()), pB , SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(workerThread , SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread , SLOT(deleteLater()));
workerThread ->start();
```

sigProduce(double) is a signal defined in the A object and slotConsume(double) is a public slot:
header of class B:

```
public slots:
 void slotConsume(double);
```

so after the program started obj B can not get the double data from obj A.Does that connect(pA,pB) code's position matters?can anyone help me?THANKS.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter when to call connect. Type of connection is resolved in runtime. Part of your code looks OK, but it is not a complete code sample. Please, provide an SSCCE with your problem.

Comment: You have `QThread *workerThread = new QThread;` twice. You cannot declare a variable with the same name twice. Is this your real code?

Comment: I reviewed my code and found that in each A or B object's doWork() function, qApp->processEvents() is necessary. I forget to call it in B's doWork() loop.And another important thing is it doesn't matter when to call the cennect function.And this is what Sazonov said.

Comment: If you have a infinite loop in `doWork` function, it is blocking your event loop. That is why you had to call `processEvents`. I don't like this design personally. I would remove the infinite loop and make a better system with a `QTimer`.

Comment: @thuga would you please show me a simple SSCCE on how to use the QTimer?Because the thread's loop is almost infinite in most cases,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before I go into the details how to solve your problem, make sure the problem is valid in the first place. If the only reason you're using threads is because you want an infinite loop, then maybe you don't need threads at all. If the work inside the loop is light, then you can just do it in the main thread with a `QTimer`. Read [this article](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#When_shouldn.27t_I_use_threads.3F) to know more about this.

Anyway the problem you have is because you have an infinite loop in your `doWork` method, which is blocking the thread's event loop. Because of this you had to resort to calling `processEvents`. However this is not a good design. A better way would be to let the thread go back to the event loop by removing the infinite loop from `doWork`.

You can then simulate a loop with a timer, and stop the timer when you want to stop the thread. Or you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with a `Qt::QueuedConnection` to call the `doWork` method from the event loop, and use a `bool` condition top stop the work. In this example I used the `invokeMethod` option:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent), _stop(false) {}

public slots:
    void doWork()
    {
        if(_stop)
            return;
        QThread::sleep(1); // simulating some heavy work here
        emit calculationComplete(1564);
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }

    void stop()
    {
        _stop = true;
    }

signals:
    void calculationComplete(int result);

private:
    bool _stop;

};

class ResultHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ResultHandler(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void handleResult(int result)
    {
        // do something with result
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Result:" << result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QThread thread_a;
    Worker worker;
    ResultHandler handler;

    QObject::connect(&worker, &Worker::calculationComplete, &handler, &ResultHandler::handleResult);
    QObject::connect(&thread_a, &QThread::started, &worker, &Worker::doWork);
    QObject::connect(&thread_a, &QThread::finished, &worker, &Worker::stop);

    worker.moveToThread(&thread_a);
    thread_a.start();

    QTimer::singleShot(5000, &thread_a, &QThread::quit); // just simulating an exit

    int result = a.exec();
    thread_a.quit();
    thread_a.wait(5000);
    return result;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. My application is in computer vision field and I currently have two worker thread, one is grabbing images and one is processing. In most cases the system is grabbing and image processing, the processing task finished its work every 200 ms. So is this situation suitable for your method?

Comment: Should I describe my plan……I use one QThread to grab the image async from the camera(here I have several cameras at the same time,so do i need to implement the same number QThread?)then your resultHandler Obj handles the grabbed images say the image processing.

Comment: @liyang I see. Then you should definitely move the image processing to a new thread. So in my example `doWork` would be what processes the image, and `calculationComplete` would send the processed image. How many threads you need is difficult to estimate. Start with a main thread and a thread for image processing. Measure the performance. If it is bad, try adding more threads. Also check out different [multithreading technologies](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html) Qt has to offer.

Comment: Thanks a lot and your advice really works.Now I have three threads, one is the grabbing thread, the other two are the processing threads that are in charge of different aspects.